# Java Transfer Object, what is it?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, dao

Directly from [this oracle article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html) about the J2EE DAO Pattern:

Everything is very clear indeed but the Transfer Object "participant" (as they call it).

Here I quote the bit I would like more insights about (especially would be useful a real life example (an easy one)).

> TransferObject
>
> This represents a Transfer Object used as a data carrier. The
> DataAccessObject may use a Transfer Object to return data to the
> client. The DataAccessObject may also receive the data from the client
> in a Transfer Object to update the data in the data source.

I am trying to use this pattern as an exercise (as a student for the exam OCPJP it requires to understand the DAO Pattern). So far I have my DataSource (mysql database), my business object (JavaBean called Person) and my DAO object interfacing properly between the database and the JavaBean (Person).

So again What exactly a Transfer Object is?

**EDIT:**
FROM THE FIRST REPLIES I UNDERSTOOD THAT ACTUALLY I KNOW WHAT A TRANFER OBJECT IS BUT I DO NOT KNOW WHAT A BUSINESS OBJECT IS... SO THE QUESTION REMAIN THE SAME BUT FOR THE BUSINESS OBJECT. NOT FOR THE TRANSFER OBJECT.

Thanks in advance and  sorry about that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not accept the best answer you got so far and post a new one about the business object?

Comment: @nakosspy you are right indeed here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008521/dao-pattern-in-java-what-is-a-business-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Transfer object is a simple class with fields and NO logic.** They are **serializable** POJOs (Plain Old Java Objects) and have accessors (getters, setters) to access fields. They are called transfer because they are used to **pass data between layers** or roughly speaking **group arguments to service method calls**, they **need not to match business objects**.

Example

```
UserLogin { // just fields that are needed to login, not a User business object
    String name;
    String password;
}

LoginService { // sample sarvice that check passwords
    boolean Login(UserLogin userLogin) {...}
}
```

Transfer Objects are distinguished from other structure-like classes by the way they are used (transferring data) not by the way they are build (fields and accessors).

Comment: Ok I thought it was the business object... so what's the business object then?

Answer (score 3):

**DTO**

DTO does not have any behavior except for storage and retrieval of its own data (accessors and mutators). DTOs are simple objects that should not contain any business logic that would require testing.

**DTO Usage**

> Case 1:  Use DTO's if the domain object is huge, but you just need a
>   few attributes of it! For large domain objects, in which the client
>   visualize, change or display only a few of its attributes. In this
>   case we recommend to use the notation: prefixDTO. This is the object
>   which the client uses to do its works. The service gets the Domain
>   Object, creates the DTO and gives it back. If this DTO is used in a
>   wizard or kind of formular in which the user may type something in
>   setting values, which means that you have to store the typed
>   information into database, then you should use in addtion to the DTOs
>   new objects called: prefixDTOData. why that? Because otherwise we
>   would force the service which writes the attributes into database to
>   iterate over the whole domain object (remember that the domain object
>   is huge) looking and comparing for changes before writing down in the
>   database.
>
> Case 2:  Use DTOs if the client has to show fields from different
>   domain objects. In this special case you may consider putting all the
>   needed attributes together already in the database creating the DTO in
>   the server which is passed to the service going to the client. The
>   client creates analoque to Case 1 a prefixDTOData an gives it back to
>   the service. the reasons are the same as in explained in Case 1.

Comment: Ok my bad I thought it was the business object... then i don't know what a business object is... my bad again

Comment: +1 :: When there are large domain objects having a <T>DTO sure helps.

Comment: Perfect answer . Also thanks @EdwardJBeckett for pointing out the generics thing

Answer (score 2):

It will transfer the data from one layer to another layer.You can call it as `DTO(DATA TRANSFER OBJECT) or`VO(VALUE OBJECT)`.

For example if we fill a form contains user details to save in the databse.First values will go to the action class.Then i need to send it to the DAO through service.So in action class i will set all the details to a class and then access it in service class